# NameError emerges when importing pylab in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

everyone, I encounter some silly problem when importing the pylab module in Anaconda Spyder IDE. Say I have the following

```
from pylab import *
```

then the spyder IDE give me the Error message like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\zhanglu\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/zhanglu/Documents/Python Scripts/test1.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pylab  # Depreciated
  File "pylab.py", line 29, in <module>
    figure() 
NameError: name 'figure' is not defined
```

It seems that `figure()` has gone wrong but I have no idea how to fix it. In fact, such snippet of code worked just well a few weeks ago, so I guess some misconduct cause the trouble but I don't know which. Becides,the IDE give me some warning before executing the code,reads like

```
from pylab import * used; unable to detect undefined names
```

Besides, I also want to know how to demonstrate the namelist of all the python modules anaconda has installed.

Comment: open an anaconda terminal and type conda list to list all of the anaconda installed packages and pip freeze for the rest. As to your other problem I am not quite sure

Comment: Thanks, jfsh003 for your help